# Method findBy() from Doctrine with DateTime

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following code, but this would not work:

```
$event= $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Event')
        ->findBy(
            array(
                "datestart" => array(new \DateTime())
            )
        );
```

I need a list of the  events, which are newer then now.

Where is my misstake?

Or isn't that able to get with the default findBy() function of doctrine ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

findBy only search for exactly matches while you need greater then. In this case and also many other cases you can write your own query. You could use DQL or the queryBuilder. If you want to be able to re-use your query on other places then you could place your query in a repository class which is a good practice too. ([check the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)). Now here you find a DQL example that you can place into your controller:

```
$events = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT e FROM AppBundle:Event e WHERE e.datestart > CURRENT_DATE()')
        ->getResult();
```

i changed your variabele to $events (with s) because you are expecting possible more than one event.